# Error on importing component from other module

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am trying to import a 'OpenDialogContentComponent' component from Module A to Module B but getting an error:

*'Cannot determine the module for class OpenDialogContentComponent in C:/Users/jitdagar/Desktop/TDP/pwt-ui-common/src/app/components/open-dialog-content/open-dialog-content.component.ts! Add OpenDialogContentComponent to the NgModule to fix it.'*

This OpenDialogContentComponent component is exported in module A and can be used in Module B with its selector. But my requirement is to import the component using the import statement.

In Module B's component:

*import { OpenDialogContentComponent } from '../../../../Module A/src/app/components/open-dialog-content/open-dialog-content.component';*

Comment: you need to add your ModuleA under imports of ModuleB

Comment: Module is already added that's why I am able to use the selector of module A's component in Module B. I want to use that component in routes by importing.

Comment: Module A could be treated as shared module and component 'OpenDialogContentComponent' is a shared component which I want to use in Module B routes.

Comment: For those who down voted, please clarify the reason of whether the question was unclear/invalid/.. I think i clarified my query with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The auto import was generating the relative path for the 'OpenDialogContentComponent' . When I replaces it with node module path, it worked.

```
import { OpenDialogContentComponent } from '../../../../ModuleA/src/app/components/open-dialog-content/open-dialog-content.component';
```

Replaces the path with the node modules path:

```
import { OpenDialogContentComponent } from '@Module/ModuleA/src/app/components/open-dialog-content/open-dialog-content.component';
```